# Adding an element to SOAP

Tags: android, xml, soap

***I wants to add a key to my SOAP object like this,***

```
  <objectKeys xsi:type="wss:ArrayOfCAdxParamKeyValue" soapenc:arrayType="wss:CAdxParamKeyValue[]">T931301SON0001</objectKeys>
```

**But when ever I tried to add this value ,am getting Soap as**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><v:Envelope   xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"    xmlns:d="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:c="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:v="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><v:Header><n0:CAdxCallingContext xmlns:n0="http://www.adonix.com/WSS"><n0:codeLang>ENG</n0:codeLang><n0:codeUser>aaa</n0:codeUser><n0:password></n0:password><n0:poolAlias>CONN</n0:poolAlias><n0:requestConfig>adxwss.optreturn=JSON</n0:requestConfig></n0:CAdxCallingContext></v:Header><v:Body><n1:read xmlns:n1="http://www.adonix.com/WSS"><publicName>SALESORD</publicName><objectKeys i:type="d:string">T931301SON0001</objectKeys></n1:read></v:Body></v:Envelope>
```

Am getting this error.

> org.xml.sax.SAXException: Found character data inside an array element while deserializing

Please let me know what I am missing?